# How did R' Yaakov Risher arrive at the exact number of responsa that he published?

Tags: history, jewish-books, responsa

Volume 1 and 3 of Shvus Yaakov have 182 responsa in each, corresponding to the numerical value of the author's name, Yaakov. Volume 2 has 188 responsa. After responsum 182 of volume 2, the author notes that, since in 5 places Yaakov is written with the *vov*, he added 6 responsa that were written during publication of the volume to make it 188 (in the volume up on Hebrewbooks, they do not have the last 6 in volume 2, but in the copy in our beis medrash, it does).

My question is, did the author just happen to have exactly that many responsa that he felt were worthy of publishing, did he add some that he felt weren't worthy of publishing in order to complete the gematria, or did he leave out some that were worthy of publishing in order to maintain the significant number?

Comment: Or, related to what the Shach ([YD 196:20](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5543)) suggested about the *T'rumas HaDeshen*, were some of the questions written by the *Sh'vus Ya'akov* himself?

Comment: @Fred nice. I was thinking the same thing as I was reading the question.

Comment: @Fred my chavrusa and I were actually compiling a makeshift list of shu"t seforim of that type (i.e. gematria numbers of teshuvos). Although with Terumas Hadeshen, it is much easier to assume the name came after the final # of teshuvos.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69876/759 gematria title

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8_%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A7_(%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8) claims the 112 chapters in the work are related to its name.