# Sefer of Unanswered questions

Tags: jewish-books, books-generally

I heard of a Sefer or page that someone published of a bunch of unanswered questions (either just on Gemara or in general). 
I don't remember the amount of questions but it's between 50-100 I believe.
Does anyone know the name of this Sefer / page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R. David Cohen (of Cong. Gvul Yaavetz in Brooklyn) has a series of seforim consisting of unanswered questions titled ואם תאמר ([I-IV](http://hebrewbooks.org/52089), [V](http://hebrewbooks.org/52087), [VI](http://hebrewbooks.org/52088)).

The author of the Chelkas Yoav has a book of (103) unanswered questions called [קבא דקשייתא](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=828&st=&pgnum=230).